# Why can't my server access my build folder?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, production-environment

Trying to get a react up into production using Heroku. The build itself worked, but when I open the app in production I get a blank screen with the text "route not found." I believe this is because the build folder is unable to be accessed, the folder and all its contents are greyed out as if it was being ignored. My other projects have never done this before, although this is the first time putting a react app on Heroku.
Here's my main.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const bp = require('body-parser')
import DbContext from "./db/DbConfig"

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

let server = express()

DbContext.connect()

server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../client/build'))

let whitelist = ['http://localhost:8080', 'https://ssb-stats.herokuapp.com'];
let corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    let originIsWhitelisted = whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1;
    callback(null, originIsWhitelisted);
  },
  credentials: true
};
// @ts-ignore
server.use(cors(corsOptions))

server.use(bp.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
server.use(bp.json())

server.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(error);
  res.status(error.status || 400).send({ error: error.message })
})

server.use('*', (req, res, next) => {
  res.status(404).send("Route not found")
})

server.listen(port, () => { console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`) })
```

I think everything in there looks fine, I'm not sure if it's a package issue or what, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../client/build')));
```

since you are accessing the upper directory, you need to create the path, not to concatenate.

Also to use `path` you need to require it: `const path = require('path');`